# Internet Explorer 10 thinks links on same domain with target="_blank" are popups and blocks them

Tags: internet-explorer-10

I just installed IE 10, i go to a site for example

http://www.example.com/a_page.html

which has some links pointing to

http://www.example.com/another_page.html

with target="_blank"

In firefox and others links open in new tab, but in IE 10 when i click i am getting a notice at the bottom of the screen:

```
Internet Explorer blocked a pop-up from www.example.com [Allow once] [Options for this site]
```

and of course no new tab, nothing loads.

Why why why... so miserable...

Version:10.0.9200.16521

Code to reproduce it:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <body>
      <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">6 maybe is dead, but 10 is alive.</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

NOTE: This code could be hosted at http://www.example.com and links pointing to same domain.

Comment: Are you able to construct a short but complete example of a problem page?

Comment: yes i updated the question details